# My advisor is using and reading academia.stackexchange, how safely I can ask questions?

Tags: support, feature-request, subjective-question

Few days ago my advisor shared on social media this platform, and also recommended for everyone at my uni to use it as a source of information and how something should be done in academia. 
I am wondering how safe my private data and locations are here? do I need to delete my account? Is someone with experience in CS can break into StackExchange server and pick location and IP information?
Do you think I should use from now on only anonymous question option and not to use account?

Comment: Most of the time when folks get into trouble here, it's because they're doing something stupid and hoping that it won't get traced back to them. So, for example, avoid posting publicly about how you're knowingly violating your university's policies and are looking for help to avoid getting caught. Probably also avoid referring to staff publically as "those jackasses" and the like. Otherwise... Consider complementing your advisor on their taste in websites!

Comment: Thank you Shog9, I dont really plan to do anything illegal in future, but I am afraid that some discussion can be interpreted as talk behind back. I never imagined that it is possible for stackexchange ( academic part ) to be so popular on every level, it look like new form of syndicate.

Comment: " I dont really plan to do anything illegal in future"  *curioser and curioser*

Answer (score 7):

> I am wondering how safe my private data and locations are here?

Your private data should be safe. Moderators and staff can see it, but must not share it. Then, you give a location publicly. But maybe that's a false flag.

> Do I need to delete my account?

That's impossible to answer.

> Is someone with experience in CS can break into StackExchange server and pick location and IP information?

Well, likely there is no system of which one can say it is absolutely impossible to break in. But then, SE is sizeable and in that business for quite some time with plenty of users with "experience in CS." Thus,  I'd say it  should be as save as most anything. Why not worry about your emails instead?  (Some info did leak in a encrypted form via the autogenerated  indenticons, as it was the hash of some personal data, but this got plugged via salting the data.)

> Do you think I should use from now on only anonymous question option and not to use account?

That's hard to tell. If your name is actually Simon and you are actually in Macau, then this could help to identify you a lot. Thus,  if it is important for you to be not identified, then you might change this.

You should also keep in mind that the content of your posts could be identifying that knows you or was part of the conversation. "Yesterday, my advisor said: {Something distinctive}." If your advisor reads this they might recognize it whether your account is anonymous or not.

Actually, think about it, specifically this post suffers this problem! It is rather self-defeating.

Comment: I am Simon and from Macau :D

Comment: thank you for your answer, so my location and IP is collected and guarded by moderators. Who are they? How can I contact them?

Comment: The moderators of this  site are the users [listed on the moderator tab](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) For how to contact them [see this post](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1831/how-should-a-user-with-a-problem-contact-a-moderator). Depending on the nature of the inquiry, you might want to contact SE staff instead. Follow "contact us" link at the bottom of the page. (Technical questions are better addressed to staff.)

Answer (score 4):

Looking over the [questions you've asked in the past](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/41198/ssimon?tab=questions), I would say that you're significantly overreacting. Many people use this forum, including (possibly) your peers, your instructors, your collaborators, and your future employers. You seem to have maintained a professional air about you since you've started; keep it up and you should be fine.

In the event that you do want to post a more sensitive question, simply log out before posting it.

On a related note, feel free to visit (and upvote!) [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/281223/139256) on the main Meta site.

Comment: thank you, thank you for analysis.

Comment: but why that question is downvoted??? so much?

Comment: @SSimon - My guess is that while this is important to sites like ours, many other sites—the main SO include—have little need for it. Its important to us but not that important overall.

Comment: How can we demand this option ? @eykanal

Comment: @SSimon - You can't "demand" anything, but you can sign out before posting. Alternatively, you can simply use stackoverflow without logging in at all.